# Python Change How Reads Numbered Files

Tags: python, string, list

I have many files labeled starting with the string "example" and ending with a number (in which the order matters).  I am renaming all of the files (in order), and instead of reading the files in order of example1, example2, example3, ..., example150, it is reading the files in order of example1, example10, example100, example 101, example 102, ..., and repeating this process.  How can I change it to read the files in sequential order?  Thanks!

Comment: Two choices: Rename your files to have leading 0 digits (example000, example001, etc), or modify your sort to sort the names numerically instead of lexically. If you want specific help, post specific code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
n = .. # amount of files 
for i in range(0, n) :
    f = open("example" + str(i), "r")
    # do something with your file
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort takes a `key` argument that can be used to set the sorting key. For your problem you may get rid of all the text, and then use `int()` to turn the string into your integer sort key:

```
for files in sorted(files, 
                    key=lambda f: int(f.replace('example','').replace('.txt',''))):
    # process the file
```

Comment: use .strip() instead of replace ;)

Comment: f.rodrigues is right. You can write `f.strip('example.txt')` instead of replace :-). A cleaner and more general solution is using regular expressions: `import re; ... int(re.sub(r'\D','',f))`

Answer (score 0):

```
files = ['example1.txt','example2.txt', 'example10.txt','example11.txt', 'example100.txt', 'example101.txt', 'example102.txt']

def sort_numericly(file_list,prefix,sufix):
    new_file_list = []
    for f in file_list:
        f = f.strip(prefix).strip(sufix)
        new_file_list.append(int(f))
    return [prefix+ str(f) + sufixfor f in sorted(new_file_list)]

print sorted(files)
print sort_numericly(files,'example','.txt')
```

Output:

```
['example1.txt', 'example10.txt', 'example100.txt', 'example101.txt', 'example102.txt', 'example11.txt', 'example2.txt']
['example1.txt', 'example2.txt', 'example10.txt', 'example11.txt', 'example100.txt', 'example101.txt', 'example102.txt']
```